# Redshift Stored Procedure Can't Work as Expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I created and ran successfully Stored Procedure in Redshift but not working as expected.
For example, I'd like to delete data in the period set by the arguments.

-- Stored Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test(parm0 varchar(100), parm1 date, parm2 date)
AS '
BEGIN
  EXECUTE
    $_$ DELETE FROM test_table_b
    WHERE $_$|| parm0 ||$_$ 
    between $_$|| parm1 ||$_$ and $_$|| parm2 ||$_$ $_$;
end;
' language plpgsql;
```

-- Run Stored procedure

```
Begin;
Call sp_test('opsdt', '2021-01-16', '2021-01-17');
Commit;
```

-- Result

```
BEGIN executed successfully

Execution time: 0.07s
Statement 1 of 3 finished

0 rows affected
Call executed successfully

Execution time: 0.18s
Statement 2 of 3 finished

COMMIT executed successfully

Execution time: 0.13s
Statement 3 of 3 finished


Script execution finished
Total script execution time: 0.38s
```

Script ran successfully, but the record '2021-01-16' and '2021-01-17' is still remained in that table.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps use a `RAISE NOTICE` to output the DELETE statement, to confirm that it is incorporating the variables you expected?

Comment: @John Rotenstein  Many thanks for useful advice, John!!  It seems to be required proper quotation. It goes successfully now with or without RAISE NOTICE. But RAISE NOTICE helps me to know what query actually executed as warning and so useful. I really appreciated your kind advice again. Have a wonderful day :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @John Rotenstein, now I could run Stored Procedure as expected.
Just simple example for someone who has the same issue.

-- Revised Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_del_test(tbl_name varchar(50), col_name varchar(50), start_dt date, end_dt date)
AS $PROC$
DECLARE
    sql        VARCHAR(MAX) := '';
BEGIN

 sql := 'DELETE FROM ' || tbl_name || ' WHERE ' || col_name || ' BETWEEN ''' || start_dt || ''' AND ''' || end_dt || '''';
 
  RAISE INFO '%', sql;
  EXECUTE sql;
END;    
$PROC$ language plpgsql;
```

-- Executed Commands

```
Begin;
Call sp_del_test('test_table_b', 'opsdt', '2021-01-23', '2021-01-24');
Commit;
```

-- Return Message

```
BEGIN executed successfully

Execution time: 0.05s
Statement 1 of 3 finished

**Warnings:
DELETE FROM test_table_b WHERE opsdt BETWEEN '2021-01-23' AND '2021-01-24'**

0 rows affected
Call executed successfully

Execution time: 0.2s
Statement 2 of 3 finished

COMMIT executed successfully

Execution time: 0.12s
Statement 3 of 3 finished


Script execution finished
Total script execution time: 0.38s
```